# yaml - difference between yaml.CLoader and yaml.FullLoader

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I tried looking for a documentation and couldn't find (except in [here](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), but the FullLoader doesn't appear there):

What is the difference between the following lines?

```
yaml.load(string_holding_yaml_content, Loader=yaml.CLoader)
yaml.load(string_holding_yaml_content, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

They both seem to do great work, but CLoader is much faster.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cloader` uses as scanner and tokenizer written in C, instead of Python that makes it much faster. The `FullLoader` is what used to be the default `Loader` and is unsafe to use when you don't have full control over the input.

If you don't have any tags of the form `!!python...` in your YAML documents, there is no reason to use the `FullLoader`.

Please note that both loaders were for YAML 1.1 last time I checked, and the YAML 1.2 specification has been out since 2009. There are also some valid (1.1) YAML that neither of these can handle, so don't be surprised if what you think is valid YAML doesn't get loaded.

Comment: is there any processing output difference between CLoader and python's Loader? Meaning do they produce the same EXACT output or are there situations where the output would differ between the two?

Comment: @JasonY This is about the loader. If by output you mean the Python data structure created, I don't think there was a difference for PyYAML version 3, but I haven't looked into detail to the changes after that release ( most seem to be relatively minor code changes  )

Comment: yes, I was curious about the output Python data structure. My current workload is using Python's Loader but it takes a long time to load yaml, I can only use CLoader if it produces the same exact data structure output